# Unexpected behaviour with negative fraction of seconds in xdata time

Tags: gnuplot

Can anybody explain the strange behaviour of gnuplot with negative fractions of seconds when plotting with xdata time? I mean the zig-zag in the middle plot. Is this a bug or am I missing anything? (gnuplot 5.2.6)

**Code:**

```
### strange behaviour with negative fractions of seconds in xdata time
reset session

set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:($1**2) w table
unset table

set multiplot layout 3,1
    plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "web-green"

    set xdata time
    set timefmt "%s"
    set format x "%H:%M:%S"
    plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red"

    set format x "%H:%M"
    plot $Data u ($1*60):2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "web-blue"

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over-complicating this.  Your data is purely in seconds.  No need to invoke "set xdata time" or "set timefmt" variants because the input is just a floating point number.  On output, set the xtic format depending on whether you want the x axis labeled in absolute time (wraps at midnight) or relative time (+/- interval).

```
### absolute vs relative time formats
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:($1**2) w table
unset table

set multiplot layout 3,1
    plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "web-green"

    set xtics time format "%tH:%tM:%tS" # relative time
    plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red"

    set xtics time format "%H:%M:%S"    # absolute time
    plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "blue"
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

[image]

But no, sorry, I cannot explain why your original plot came out with a zigzag.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know. instead of using `set xdata time`, etc. just `set xtics time format ...`. Although my example would be an over-complication, it shouldn't show a zigzag for negative numbers. By the way, can you reproduce it? Or is it a peculiarity of Win7/gnuplot 5.2.6?

Comment: Gnuplot 5 distinguishes between use of time formats during input and during output. They are not the same. "set xtics time" affects only the creation of tic labels on output.   "set xdata time" and "set timefmt" affect how input data is read, i.e. input is interpreted as a string with format controlled by "set timefmt".

Comment: Note: The command `set xdata time` is left over from gnuplot 4 and should probably be deprecated. It was poorly designed because it confuses input column with plot axis. I.e. what if you want to read a time value on input but not use it for an axis coordinate?  That was hard to do in version 4.  In version 5 `set xdata time` is never needed because you can use the `timecolumn(input_column, time_format)` function instead, which is not tied to any particular axis.